# @DeclareMixin added methods not visible by other classes

Tags: java, aspectj, ajdt

I'm trying to use @DeclareMixin for the first time, and either I am doing something incorrect, or there is a bug somewhere.

I've published my sample code to github:  https://github.com/benze/AspectJError.git.  I'm pasting the little bits here as well.

If I look at the compiled code of ApplyAspect.class using a decompiler, I can see that ajc has properly added in the implemented interface.
However, the compiler complains in Test that ApplyAspect does not have the setCreated() or the getCreated() methods.

Additionally, if I try to compile the project from the command line, I get the same compilation errors as well.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, or if there is a bug somewhere else with @DeclareMixin directive.

Interface CreatedBean.java:

```
public interface CreatedBean {
    public Object getCreated();
    public void setCreated(final Object created);
}
```

Implementation CreatedBeanImpl.java:

```
public class CreatedBeanImpl implements CreatedBean{
        private Object created;

        public Object getCreated(){
            return this.created;
        }

        public void setCreated(final Object created ){
            this.created = created;
        }
}
```

Aspect definition:

```
@Aspect
public class DeclareMixinAspect {
    @DeclareMixin("com.benze.bo.ApplyAspect")
    public CreatedBean auditableBeanMixin(){
        return new CreatedBeanImpl();
    }
}
```

Class being advised (com.benze.bo pkg):

```
public class ApplyAspect {
    private String name = "test class";
}
```

Class trying to use ApplyAspect:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplyAspect aa = new ApplyAspect();
        aa.setCreated(new Date());
        System.out.println( aa.getCreated().toString());
        System.out.println(aa.toString());
        System.out.println("all done");
    }
}
```

The pom is very basic with only the aspectj plugin (and dependencies) added.  I'm using AJ 1.8.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need casts in your Test class:

```
((CreatedBean)aa).setCreated(new Date());

System.out.println(((CreatedBean)aa).getCreated().toString());
```

IIRC the reason is that annotation style code is intended to be compilable with javac, which would not know about the affect of `DeclareMixin`.

Comment: Ugg - needing to cast everytime is ugly.  I know in AJ syntax, I can declare the implementation as part of the interface (inner static aspect) and then just apply the interface with a simple `declare parents: xxx implements yyy`.  Then I don't need to cast the `aa` bean.  Is there a way to combine the two?  Ie: use AJ syntax to add the interface implementation (instead of annotation style), but keep the implementation and interface separate (each in its own .java file)?

Comment: Casting resolves the issue, but as I said, I would much rather not have to case if possible.  IIRC, using the AJ notation does not require me to cast; is there an equivalent in Annotation style?